# How to stop google maps clearing the contents of DIV it is assigned to

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to add some controls to a div containing the google maps, but when the map is assigned to the div it clears its contents. Is there a way to prevent this?

My reason for this is a don't want to use the controls api + I want my controls to be positioned absolutely inside this div.

Comment: another mindless downvote, enjoy your -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the [**mapOption**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#MapOptions) `noClear` to `true`